# Forward Incoming Traffic with Windows hosts file?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosts, hosts-file

A long time ago I found some guide that showed how to use the Windows Hosts file to forward incoming traffic to another local IP/Port. We setup a clients server on one IP/Port, and they wanted it changed to another IP/Port on the same machine, but are now asking that we forward UDP/TCP traffic to it as well.

I am pretty sure this is doable but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it now after Google searching for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mistaken.  The windows hosts file can not forward ports.  It is a DNS lookup service only and will never do anything with ports, only map between host names and IP addresses.