# Windows redirect by port?

Tags: windows, redirect, port, hosts, hosts-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward Incoming Traffic with Windows hosts file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/288550/forward-incoming-traffic-with-windows-hosts-file)

In Windows you can redirect traffic from a host by using the `hosts` file.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

example

```
127.0.0.1 cp97384.edgefcs.net
```

Is there a way to do this with **all** traffic from a port? Something like

```
127.0.0.1 :1935
```

I have seen on linux you can do this with `iptables`. I have heard of solutions for Windows XP but nothing for Windows 7.

The solution does not necessarily have to use the `hosts` file, as I am pretty sure that is not even possible.

```
Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
127.0.0.1       1935        64.210.72.117   1935
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to redirect traffic coming FROM this windows machines or TO this windows machine?  I am trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this with netsh interface portproxy command, read here for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776297%28WS.10%29.aspx

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1935 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=1935 connectaddress=[ip of hostname]
```

Never used it before but seems to be applicable here.

Comment: Even if I include the hostname, this command does not work.

Comment: Can you post your output from "netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4" ?